# mapeo javascript

Tags: javascript, map

```
  // this.tareas = [
      //    {tarea: 'compras', prioridad: 1},
      //    {tarea: 'dar clases', prioridad: 3},
      //    {tarea: 'operaciones', prioridad: 2}
      //  ];
```

// Escribe una función que retorne un arreglo con sólo los nombres (tarea)

getTareas() {

```
const indexed = persona.map((tarea) => persona.tareas);
    
}
```

Se que tengo que utilizar la opcion .map pero nose como llevarlo a cabo

Comment: [Esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/435015/2) es la que origino esta otra. La verdad que es una lástima ver la falta de motivación para resolver tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Tu arreglo se llama tareas pero estas usando la variable persona en tu funcion y esa variable no existe.  La forma correcta seria asi:

```js
 this.tareas = [
          {tarea: 'compras', prioridad: 1},
          {tarea: 'dar clases', prioridad: 3},
          {tarea: 'operaciones', prioridad: 2}
        ];


function getTareas() {

const indexed = this.tareas.map((tarea) => tarea.tarea);
console.log(indexed);
    
}

getTareas();
```

Comment: Hubiese hecho exactamente lo mismo, estaba pensando enrealidad justo esto